# Setting cookies on nginx server

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cookies, nginx

In fact, I am working on a small PHP script. I am using an ajax post to get some info and store them in a variable named cookie. after that this variable is user to set a cookie this way(This code is set as an inline javascript in the page):

```
$.ajax({
                           type: "POST",
                           url: "/ajax.php",
                           data: "case=make&ck="+j,
                           success: function(msg){}
                         });
```

and in the ajax.php file here is the code i am using :

```
$pr = $_POST['ck'];
$cookie_name = "ck";
$cookie_value = $ck;
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
```

everything works fine and the cookies are set. but when refreshing the page and getting the cookies value using php ($_COOKIE) someetimes it returns the exact cookie sometimes it returns other users cookie.
I am also using CloudFlare in addition to Nginx. Can it be a caching problem ? how can I solve this issue ?
**EDIT N 1:**
I am now sure it is a caching problem: When I use ?tmp=[random numbers] at the end of the URL of the page the cookie is always exact.